# Cocos2d + box2D remove sprite from world

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

Should be easy but i don't have find...

I have a lot of sprites in my world and on a moment X, i need to destroy multiples sprites.

With the code below, i can remove this sprite by tag number:

```
CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)[self getChildByTag:TagFromMyArray];
[self removeChild:sprite cleanup:YES];
```

The problem is the body that remain on screen...and crash the game on the next tick.

With the code below i can find "a body":

```
for(b2Body *b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext()) {
        if (b->GetUserData() != NULL) {
            CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)b->GetUserData();
            if (sprite.tag = [[[myGrille.grille objectAtIndex:point.x] objectAtIndex:point.y]blockTag]) {
                [self removeChild:sprite cleanup:YES];
                world->DestroyBody(b);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it remove every body on the world.

Isn't b a reference to a unique body ?

Answer (score 1):

I was around this for hours and it was a small error...

Just have to replace "=" with "==" in the last if condition.